# Laravel : Session data to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following code, In which i am checking for error.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger {{ (\Session::has('message') && \Session::get('form', 'login') == 'login') ? '' : 'display-hide' }}">
    <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
    <span>
        {!! \Session::has('message') ? \Session::get('message') : 'Please correct your fields.' !!}
    </span>
</div>
```

On the controller side i have :

```
return redirect()
        ->back()
        ->with('message', 'Incorrect email or password.')
        ->with('form', 'login')
        ->withInput(\Input::except('password'));
```

The thing is that the message is not showing there.

Just the page refreshes and no message comes up.

Any idea ? Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply on your view use `\Session::pull('message')` instead of `\Session::get('message')`.

It is that simple .

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller

```
return redirect()
        ->back()
        ->with('message', 'Incorrect email or password.')
        ->with('form', 'login')
        ->withInput(\Input::except('password'));
```

And in your View

```
@if(Session::has('message')  && Session::has('form'))
<div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-success">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
{!! Session::get('message') !!}
</div>
</span>
@endif
```

**Note :** You can have your own html in the condition, throw your message in your way and modify condition according to your need.

Comment: What are the changes ? plz comment at the changes

Comment: I am not clear with the user's html, So i have put the conditions openly like `@if(Session::has('message')  && Session::has('form'))`

Comment: @sulthanAllaudeen Sorry for late replying...its still not working.

Answer (score 0):

As the [laravel 5.2 documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirects) says

```
<div class="alert alert-danger {{ (session('message') && session('form') === 'login') ? '' : 'display-hide' }}">
    <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
    <span>
        {!! session('message') ? session('message') : 'Please correct your fields.' !!}
    </span>
</div>

                        //OR

return redirect()
    ->back()
    ->with('message', 'Incorrect email or password.')
    ->with('form', 'login')
    ->with('classType', 'display-hide')
    ->withInput(\Input::except('password'));



<div class="alert alert-danger {{ session('classType') or '' }}">
    <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
    <span>
        {{ session('message') or 'Please correct your fields.' }}
    </span>
</div>
```